# Change of variables in integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

Im trying to understand what kind of variable change in integrals is legit.
In my book's it states that the function the deriviative of the function that we change should be continious, but I've seen in many places that sometimes it dosent have to be like that.

For example,

consider $ \int\frac{\cot x}{\sin^{2}x}dx $ .

I want to make the change:

$ u=\cot x $.

but $ \left(\cot x\right)'=-\frac{1}{\sin^{2}x} $ isnt continious in $ 0 $.
Is it still legit ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It needs to be continuous in the integration range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change of variables in **improper** integrals needs care.  In
the divergent improper integral
$$
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cot x}{\sin^2 x}\;dx
$$
the change of variables $u = \cot x$ yields
$$
\int_0^0 u\;du = 0 .
$$

---

What about proper integrals?  See the proof at
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Proof) .  Suppose we want to make the substitution $u = \varphi(x)$ on $[a,b]$ to conclude
$$
\int_a^b f(\varphi(x))\varphi'(x)\;dx = \int_{\varphi(a)}^{\varphi(b)} f(u)\;du .
\tag1$$
In that proof we need to know that $\varphi'$ is integrable on $[a,b]$.  To get this conclusion, it is not enough to know that $\varphi'$ exists on $[a,b]$.  But it is enough to know that $\varphi'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.  In fact, it would be enough that $\varphi'$ is bounded and piecewise continuous.

A special case of $(1)$ is where we take $f$ to be the constant $1$:
$$
\int_a^b \varphi'(x)\;dx = \varphi(b) - \varphi(a)
\tag2$$
Even for this conclusion, merely assuming $\varphi'$ exists everywhere on $[a,b]$ is not enough.

Comment: What about proper integrals? Will this change of variable be legit in regular integral? Also, in your example, what is the right way to change the variables?